# Remote desktop connection over internet without port forwarding?

Tags: remote-desktop, connection, port-forwarding

let's say that we have this situation. I want to remote desktop connection to my friend over the internet, but I don't have premission for port forwarding on the router, and my friend also can't configure his router. So the question is how to connect to computer without port forwarding, I know that is out there some programs like teamviewer, or some else that solve that task, but what I looking for is the some free site that can make "bridge" between are two computer, or is it possible to install on computer some program that simulate virtual router or something like this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SIof7kFTgJE  ....
I need this cause I have my own simple remote desktop connection program, but I can't connect to other computer outside network cause don't have premission to configure router :(

any comment, link, advice, or tutorials will be very helpful :)

Comment: If you don't have permission to configure the router, shouldn't you ask whoever administers the network? They seem to not want you to be doing this...

Comment: ... yes it's true, but let's say that I'm administrator and forget password from router, and don't have physically acess to them, ... so the question is same,...how to desktop connection over internet without port forwarding?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've not tried any of these solutions but here's a list of some free services/software :

http://infoworld.com/d/mobilize/infoworld-review-free-remote-access-tools-windows-and-mac-018?page=0,0

From all reports the GBridge solution ranks highly.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

You could use some sort of [vpn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network) implementation; that would effectively put you on the same network. For windows systems; I use [hamachi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamachi_%28software%29).

Comment: Hamachi actually needs port forwarding for direct tunneling. Without port forwarding, it makes a relayed connection which is very very slow

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I've done this without problems between two PCs running different versions of Windows (XP and 7) without doing anything special at either end as-far-as router configurations goes. It just worked -- so go ahead and give it a try.

Comment: thnx for advice ... I tried a lot of time, but it seem that doesn't work for me ...

Comment: @martioneau: Perhaps the routers in question had [UPnP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UPnP) enabled?

Comment: I don't know, maybe ... let's say that have UPnP enabled ...

Comment: @oKtosiTe: Not sure about the far end, but UPnP is definitely disabled on my router at this end (the one running XP Pro).

Answer (score 0):

You can use mqtt to exchange data between a a terminal on the remote PC (you could in theory proxy also a VNC binary data) and the web page by using a broker in the cloud.